# Getting ember to run under docker on Windows Quickstart

Tags: ember.js, docker, ember-cli, docker-compose

Working through this tutorial on setting up ember-cli in a Docker container:
http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/setting-ember-cli-development-environment-ember-21/

Here are my steps:

1. Created docker-compose.yml in an empty folder on the host machine
2. Launched Docker Quickstart to get a terminal
3. Changed to the folder with the .yml
4. Ran the two docker-compose commands below from the terminal (added -d because without that you get a message that interactive mode is not supported)
5. Ran docker ps -a to verify that the container was running
6. Ran docker inspect CONTAINER_ID to find the ip address of the running container
7. Found the IP address at an odd location (172.17.0.2)
8. Attempted to access port 4200 on that IP from the host Windows machine browser and also from the Docker CL via curl but without success.
9. Ran docker ps -a and found that both containers that had been instantiated had exited.
10. Now if I try to start the container again it just exits immediately

docker-compose run -d --rm ember init
docker-compose run -d --rm ember server

What am I missing to get up and running?  Do I need to open ports on the Default VM running in Virtualbox? How do I diagnose why the container keeps exiting?

Comment: If you have proper port mapping in your compose file, the server should be available at 192.168.99.100:4200. The IP address you found is the internal IP for the docker container, but you need the IP for the docker-machine (which is a Virtualbox Machine on Windows).

Comment: The exit issue is more complex. You should run without `-d` and watch the output.

Comment: $ docker-compose run --rm ember server  

[31mERROR[0m: Interactive mode is not yet supported on Windows.  

Please pass the -d flag when using `docker-compose run`.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Docker Toolbox?

Comment: Was able to get the logs on the container that exited with this command; I'm getting this same error if I try to run this in the Windows host environment:    $ docker logs embercontainer_ember_run_3
Cannot find module 'concat-map'
Error: Cannot find module 'concat-map'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)

Comment: @warmoverflow Yes using the latest version of Docker Toolbox; had installed it pretty recently but just to make sure I uninstalled and reinstalled it.  Looking at the logs, for the container instantiated for the init command there is an untar error, and then for the container instantiated for the ember serve command there is the 'concat-map' error.  npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /root/.npm/underscore.string/2.3.3/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /root/.npm/underscore.string/2.3.3/package.tgz

Comment: Ok finally resolved it. issue with the module resolution may have been long file name resolution on windows because after I moved the source folder to the root of the host I was able to get ember serve running under windows. Then from the terminal window I ran docker-compose up (-d) and was able to launch the container successfully and then was able to access port 4200 at the IP you specified.

Answer (score 1):

First I would suggest using `docker-compose up`, that is most likely what you want.

To see the logs for a detached container you can run `docker logs <container name>`. If there are any errors you'll see them there.

A likely cause of the "container exit" is because the process goes into the background. Docker requires a process to stay in the foreground, but many `serve` commands will background by default. To keep the process in the foreground you can sometimes add use a flag like `--foreground` or `--no-daemon`, but I'm not sure if one exists for ember.

If that flag doesn't exist, it's likely that `ember server` is just checking if stdin/stdout are connected to a tty. By default they are not. You can add these lines to your docker-compose.yml to fix it:

```
stdin_open: True
tty: True
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally resolved it. The issue with the module resolution may have been long file name resolution on windows because after I moved the source folder to the root of the host I was able to get ember serve running under windows.

Then from the terminal window I ran the commands to init and launch ember-server

```
docker-compose run -d --rm ember init
docker-compose run -d --rm ember server
```

Then did:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

which launched the containers successfully and then I was able to access the Ember page served up at the IP:Port specified earlier in the comments

http://192.168.99.100:4200/